# Vue-Test-Utils, Jest, Unit-Test: Cannot read property of grand child component using mount and &refs method-call in child-component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

i'm having an issue to get my unit-test working with following set-up using mount (not shallowMount) in beforeEach unit-test setup:

Interacting components:

- Parent-Component A (Getting validation-information of component B and sending data to vuex store if data is validated)
- Child-Component B (Calling validateForm-method of component C via $refs keyword to send validation status next to component A)
- Grand-Child Component C (Contains object to be validated)

Process:

- validateForm() will be first called in component C or B. Imagine an input form with some input fields (comp C)
- To validate the entries there is an Ok-Button (@click -> validateForm() executed) in C to save object in vuex store via computed getter and setter
- In B which integrates C there is a button called like "create another object" which also calls the same validateForm() function of child-comp C via $refs call - The values of validation are sent via events from grand-child to child and from child to parent
- In parent (A) the validated object will be dispatched to store via click on button (addBlaToStore).

`validateForm()` function in compenent C:

```
validateForm() {
    let valid = true

    this.$refs.ComponentC.forEach(function(bla) {
        if (!bla.validateForm()) {
        valid = false
        }
    });

    return valid;
}
```

Unit-Test (Test-File for Component A):

- The data for the object are already set in the state in test file. Means the data should be valid and function call expected, because all needed data are in store.

  ```
    test('Button triggers add bla action', () => {
        // arrange


        // act
        wrapper.findComponent({ ref: "addBlaToStore" }).vm.$emit("button-click");

        // assert
        expect(actions.addBla).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  ```

Error in log after test run:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"
```

I've already resolved all errors which occured in log after unit test runs in terms of missing getters, actions etc. but according to the last actual error it seems that testing tool does not know component c (undefined).

I thought that with mount the child components also will be mounted? Does this not affect child-components of child-components (grand child?)

How do I have to declare Component C in my test-file so vue test utils is aware of?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At what point are you calling the top `validateForm()`? It's possible the `$refs` are not yet available at that time.

Comment: `validateForm()` will be first called in component C or B. Imagine an input form with some input fields (comp C). To validate the entries there is an Ok-Button (@click -> `validateForm()` executed) in C to save object in vuex store via computed getter and setter.

In B which integrates C there is a button called like "create another object" which also calls the same `validateForm()` function of child-comp C via $refs call.

The values of validation are sent via events from grand-child to child and from child to parent. In parent the validated object will be dispatched to store via button.

Comment: That's a bit much to visualize. Can you provide a link to a reproduction?